# What is that? Deserialization tries to invoke compiler?

Tags: c#, deserialization

Check out this stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/Xy5zgQgi

With this exception message:

```
Timed out waiting for a program to execute.
The command being executed was 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe"
/noconfig /fullpaths 
@"C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\lfbuk35v.cmdline".
```

Can someone care to explain?

Comment: Is this on compiling the program? Do you have a pre/post build event that is hanging?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx Scroll down to `Dynamically Generated Assemblies`

Comment: It is because I delete tmp folder from something other, on regular basis - it seems that it occurred at exact time my loader wanted to de-serialize a class.  Ah...

Comment: It's usually polite and ok to say what's bothering you when downvoting.  What is wrong with the question that tries to shed light on some interesting workings of .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to serialize something there is code being generated that handles the serialization.
It generates a temporary assembly that handles the serialization code.
As the built in serialization isn't very good, not for binaries neither for XML/Json I would recommend that you use a free third party library for that.